Is the set of all regex that match themselves countably infinite?
With my meager computability knowledge, I believe that this question is equivalent to "Is the problem of enumerating all regex that match themselves decidable?" or maybe some variant on that idea.
And of course, by regex I mean regular expression in their simple, stack-less form.
As an example, the regex a will match itself.
Conversely, the regex [a] will not, because it will look for a as the only possible first character and not find it.
Going further, .*[a]? matches itself because the .* will resolve to the entire regex and the [a]? will resolve to nothing.

Can you give an example of "match themselves"?

Match itself and maybe other things: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6798/self-matching-regex or match only itself: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/28821/regex-that-only-matches-itself ?  The answers at those pages might also indicate that you may want to be a bit more specific about which regex syntax (or syntaces) you are considering.

Infinite: sure, every string of $n$ as matches itself. Countable: sure, since the set of regexes is countable. Decidable: sure, since regular expression matching is decidable.

This heavily depends on the language you use to write regexps. Regexps at heart are a data structure, not a string, and there are a lot of ways to write a regexp as a string.

Finite length strings in any alphabet are countable so it can be at most countable. So if you can find any infinite family of regex that match themselves it will be countably infinite.
